# Where in Rails app to set PostgreSQL session-specific configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search, initialization

I want to set a search configuration for all of my rails (2.3) app's connections like so:

"SET default_text_search_config = 'public.my_search_config';"

Where is the most correct place to do this? An initializer? monkey-patching the adapter?

Examples welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

i would go with initializer. Monkey patch in the adapter i would avoid since it could bring more oddness to be debugged. Every single bug that appear in the future in your application you will think "maybe it is related with that monkey patching"

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but when I tried: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET default_text_search_config = 'public.my_search_config';") in an initializer, it failed saying the db wasn't connected.

Comment: because it is not ActiveRecord::Base that is connected to your database. Open a console and do two tests:
ActiveRecord::Base.connected? 
and then
NameOfYourModel.connected?
The first one will be false and the second one true...

Comment: The issue is with connection pooling. It runs my command on the initial connection, but if that is closed or a new connection is created, it would not have it run. I think the proper place to do it is in establish_connection..